# Remote LLDB debugging - Docker container

Tags: linux, debugging, docker, lldb, archlinux

I'm trying to set up a remote debugging with LLDB 4.0.1.
There's a docker (17.06.0-ce) container with Arch linux.
Docker container is set in [privileged mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities), so now LLDB can be started in container.
Container contains core_service which is Rust executable.

Commands run inside container

`(lldb) target create target/debug/core_service
Current executable set to 'target/debug/core_service' (x86_64).
(lldb) process launch
Process 182 launched: '/srv/core_service/target/debug/core_service' (x86_64)`

Problem exists with remote debugging, lldb-server is started inside container with `lldb-server platform --server --listen 0.0.0.0:1234`.
I can connect from host lldb to container lldb-server, but I can't attach/create processes.

Commands run on host (lldb-server in container = localhost:1234)

`(lldb) platform select remote-linux
  Platform: remote-linux
 Connected: no
(lldb) platform connect connect://localhost:1234
  Platform: remote-linux
    Triple: x86_64-*-linux-gnu
OS Version: 4.12.4 (4.12.4-1-ARCH)
    Kernel: #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 28 18:54:18 UTC 2017
  Hostname: 099bd76c07c9
 Connected: yes
WorkingDir: /srv/core_service
(lldb) target create target/debug/core_service
Current executable set to 'target/debug/core_service' (x86_64).
(lldb) process launch
error: connect remote failed (Connection refused)
error: process launch failed: Connection refused`

How can I fix it? Are there any docker, arch linux settings that would cause this error?

It seems, like there's some problem with lldb-server permissions in docker container.

Commands run on host (lldb-server in container)

`(lldb) platform shell ps -A
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 bash
    9 ?        00:00:00 nginx
   10 ?        00:00:00 nginx
   11 ?        00:00:00 lldb-server
   25 ?        00:00:00 core_service
   59 ?        00:00:00 lldb-server
   68 ?        00:00:00 ps
(lldb) platform shell kill -9 25
(lldb) platform process launch target/debug/core_service
error: connect remote failed (Connection refused)
error: Connection refused
(lldb) platform process launch anything
error: connect remote failed (Connection refused)
error: Connection refused`

But I can't figure out what can it be. lldb-server is run as root in container, I can execute shell commands using lldb.

Comment: Try adding `--cap-add=ALL` also and see if that helps? I am not sure it would but just in case it does

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried with `--cap-add=ALL` , but there's still the same problem.

Comment: See if my latest answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is needed both *platform* port (1234 in your case) and *gdbserver* port (randomly generated by default). You can enforce the *gdbserver* port by *lldb-server* option **--gdbserver-port**.

Tested on Fedora 29 x86_64:

```
docker run --privileged -p 5000:5000 -p 5001:5001 fedora bash -c 'dnf -y install lldb;lldb-server platform --server --listen 0.0.0.0:5000 --gdbserver-port 5001'
```

and

```
echo 'int main(){}' >main.c;gcc -g -o main main.c;lldb -o 'platform select remote-linux' -o 'platform connect connect://localhost:5000' -o "target create ./main" -o 'b main' -o 'process launch'

(lldb) process launch
Process 45 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'main', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000000000040110f main`main at main.c:1
-> 1    int main(){}

Process 45 launched: '/root/main' (x86_64)
(lldb) _
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the server cannot see any process on the host. It is still wrapped in its own PID namespace. When you launch the LLDB server, use a host pid name space

```
docker run --pid=host --privileged <yourimage>
```

Hopefully this will allow your container see all the host processes

Comment: I tried it, but both executable and lldb-server are run inside container, so it didn't helped. It's weird because if I use `docker exec -it /bin/bash` and run lldb, I can launch process without problems. Problem is only with lldb-server. Now I also set `--pid=host` and could see this process on my host, so I tried to connect to it from my host lldb, but it didn't work either, there was the same error.